# How to disable 'indentexpr' for HTML files?

Tags: vim

When editing HTML files I have

```
indentexpr=HtmlIndent()
     Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/html.vim
```

I want to disable it. `setlocal indentexpr=` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` don't work. What more can I do?

Vim 7.4.

Comment: Try `~/.vim/after/indent/html.vim`

Comment: Need to add `setlocal indentexpr=` into file `~/.vim/after/indent/html.vim`. Empty is not enough.

Comment: Same as `:h ftplugin-overrule` (3).